# CSV writing strings of text that need a unique delimiter

Tags: python, csv, delimiter, openoffice-calc

I wrote an HTML parser in python used to extract data to look like this in a csv file:

```
    itemA, itemB, itemC, Sentence that might contain commas, or colons: like this,\n
```

so I used a delmiter ":::::" thinking that it wouldn't be mined in the data

```
    itemA, itemB, itemC, ::::: Sentence that might contain commas, or colons: like this,::::\n
```

This works for most of the thousands of lines, however, apparently a colon : offset this when I imported the csv in Calc.

My question is, what is the best or a unique delimiter to use when creating a csv with many variations of sentences that need to be separated with some delimiter?  Am I understanding delimiters correctly in that they separate the values within a CSV?

Comment: Use a separator character outside the set used in the data, like `chr(255)`.

Comment: @martineau I used an uncommon sequence as a delimiter (~~~) but in the future I believe this is the best answer!  How would you write chr(255) to a file?  output.write(chr(255))?

Comment: Yes, you could write it via `chr(255)` or specify to use it when using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) via the keyword argument `delimiter=chr(255)`. Would you like me to add this as an answer?

Comment: @martineau I would pick it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested informally in a comment, unique just means you need to use some character that won't be in the data — `chr(255)` might be a good choice. For example:

**Note:** The code shown is for Python 2.x — see comments for a Python 3 version.

```
import csv

DELIMITER = chr(255)
data = ["itemA", "itemB", "itemC",
        "Sentence that might contain commas, colons: or even \"quotes\"."]

with open('data.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=DELIMITER)
    writer.writerow(data)

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=DELIMITER)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Output:

```
['itemA', 'itemB', 'itemC', 'Sentence that might contain commas, colons: or even "quotes".']
```

If you're not using the `csv` module and instead are writing and/or reading the data manually, then it would go something like this:

```
with open('data.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(DELIMITER.join(data) + '\n')

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    row = infile.readline().rstrip().split(DELIMITER)
    print row
```

Comment: For anyone interested, a Python 3 version of this answer has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58384160/355230).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, delimiters separate values within each line of a CSV file. There are two strategies to delimiting text that has a lot of punctuation marks. First, you can quote the values, e.g.:

```
Value 1, Value 2, "This value has a comma, <- right there", Value 4
```

The second strategy is to use tabs (i.e., `'\t'`).

Python's built-in CSV module can both read and write CSV files that use quotes. Check out the example code under [the `csv.reader` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader). The built-in csv module will handle quotes correctly, e.g. it will escape quotes that are in the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files usually use double quotes `"` to wrap long fields that might contain a field separator like a comma. If the field contains a double quote it's escaped with a backslash: `\"`.

Comment: I'll try it now, but I'm concerned that the text I extract will have double quotes within it and misalign everything