# Is there a work around for using multi-character delimiters for `csv.reader`?

Tags: python

Currently, only one character is allowed

> Dialect.delimiter A one-character string used to separate fields. It
>   defaults to ','.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter

Is there a work around for multi-character delimiters ?

I am asking because I am working with very messy text data, which has pretty much instances of every sort of characters, so I need a rare combination of characters to effectively seperate values.

Comment: CSV quotes values that contain the delimiter so there is no need to use anything but `','`. The place where one might want to use a multiple character delimiter is when reading an existing file.

Comment: If it's a truly rare combination of characters as a delimiter, you should be able to simply use the `str.split` method to split the lines with the said delimiter.

Comment: You may find [How to give 2 characters in “delimiter” using 'csv' module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758158/how-to-give-2-characters-in-delimiter-using-csv-module) helpful.

Comment: Instead of a rare _combination_ of characters, my answer to [CSV writing strings of text that need a unique delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001882/csv-writing-strings-of-text-that-need-a-unique-delimiter) might suffice.

Comment: @martineau looks like a promising deliminiter. Is there any reason for that one?

Comment: `chr(255)` represents the last character in an 8-bit character set, with all of its bits set to 1. It has no intrinsic meaning so is unlikely to to be present in any actual data in the file. Note that the answer to the linked question is for Python 2.x, so I'm not sure how it will work in Python 3.x with its default utf-8 encoded strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the first part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22049410/355230) to the question [CSV writing strings of text that need a unique delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001882/csv-writing-strings-of-text-that-need-a-unique-delimiter) adapted to work in Python 3.7:

```
import csv

DELIMITER = chr(255)
data = ["itemA", "itemB", "itemC",
        "Sentence that might contain commas, colons: or even \"quotes\"."]

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=DELIMITER)
    writer.writerow(data)

with open('data.csv', 'r', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=DELIMITER)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```